# run the script every 30 minutes bash

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I want to run the script every 30 minutes with cron but I have problem with my code.
In every 30 min I have to kill old script and run it again. I have somethink like this, but it is not working:

```
    cd /var/www/scripts
    pkill -f bot
    now="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
    screen -S bot 
    node mybot.js >> logi/logi_$now.txt
```

Comment: In what way is it not working? What do you expect it to do and what does it do instead?

Comment: node mybot.js >> logi/logi_$now.txt   this line is not working, script has stopped in screen -S bot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may not use `screen` for running things in background in a script. Use ampersand (`&`) to background a process and `nohup` so it won't be killed when cron script exits. Also remember a subprocess PID in a file.

Something like this:

```
kill -- "$(cat mybot.pid)"
now="$(date +%Y%m%d%H%M%S)"
nohup node mybot.js >> "logi/logi_$now.txt" &
echo $! > mybot.pid
```

Answer (score 1):

use `crontab` :

```
 crontab -l

*/30 * * * * /path/to/your/command
```

save and run

Comment: format :   # m h  dom mon dow   command
                  */30 * * * * /path/to/your/command

Answer (score 0):

The line

```
    node mybot.js >> logi/logi_$now.txt
```

is never reached, as `screen -S <session name>` will start a screen session and therefore a new shell **and connect to it**. The rest of the script would only execute once that 'inner' session terminates.

`screen` is more for interactive use. Calling it in a script like this is rather strange. I guess you want to have `node mybot.js >> logi/logi_$now.txt` running in the background, so that your script can terminate while `node` keeps running. See [Redirecting stdout & stderr from background process](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4298169/redirecting-stdout-stderr-from-background-process) and [Node.js as a background service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4018154/node-js-as-a-background-service) for options how to do that.